# Dynamic Query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have two different tables in my database,such as

```
db=# select * from pg_tables where tablename like '%enhancedreports03_1970_01_01%';
```

schemaname |          tablename           |     tableowner      |  tablespace  | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers
    ------------+------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------
     reports    | enhancedreports03_1970_01_01 | ss_agent_summarizer | rpt_data_tbs | t          | f        | f
    (1 row)

```
db=# select * from pg_tables where tablename like '%enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01%';
```

schemaname |           tablename            |     tableowner      |  tablespace  | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers
    ------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------
     reports    | enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 | ss_agent_summarizer | rpt_data_tbs | t          | f        | f
    (1 row)

The requirement is to take the CSV Backup, I tried using the following dynamic query

```
db=# select 'copy ' || '"'|| "schemaname" ||'"' || '.' ||'"'|| "tablename" ||'"'  || ' from ' || ' ''/home/postgres/' || schemaname || '_' || tablename || '.' || 'csv.gz''' || ' delimiter ''' || ',' || ''' CSV' || ';' from pg_tables where tablename like '%enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01%' order by schemaname,tablename;
                                                                        ?column?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    copy "reports"."enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01" from  '/home/postgres/reports_enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01.csv.gz' delimiter ',' CSV;
```

But I need the result set to be something like this

```
 copy "reports"."enhancedreports03_1970_01_01" from  '/home/postgres/reports_enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01.csv.gz' delimiter ',' CSV;
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your query like

```
db=# select 'copy ' || '"'|| "schemaname" ||'"' || '.' ||'"'|| "tablename" ||'"'  || ' from ' || ' ''/home/postgres/' || schemaname || '_' || tablename || '.' || 'csv.gz''' || ' delimiter ''' || ',' || ''' CSV' || ';' from pg_tables where tablename like '%enhancedreports03%' order by schemaname,tablename;
```

I think this will give you your desire result or you can write a function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_export_table_csv(query text, filename text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    MySql   TEXT;:='COPY ('||SqlQuery||' ) TO '||CHR(39)||
    FileName||CHR(39)||' WITH DELIMITER '||CHR(39)||','||CHR(39)||' CSV HEADER';
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%',MySql;
    EXECUTE MySql;
END; $function$

;
```

then use the query like

```
 db=# select 'copy ' || '"'|| "schemaname" ||'"' || '.' ||'"'|| "tablename" ||'"'  || ' from ' || ' ''/home/postgres/' || schemaname || '_' || tablename || '.' || 'csv.gz''' || ' delimiter ''' || ',' || ''' CSV' || ';' from pg_tables where tablename like 'enhancedreports03_1970_01_01%' order by schemaname,tablename;
```

Comment: No the dynamic query is not giving me the desired result set..What i need is the pointed table should be copied to the table without underscore zero (_0)..i.e)enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 to enhancedreports03_1970_01_01

Comment: sorry i really don't understand your current question will you please explain it... sorry again..

Comment: actualy i dont understand the need of dianamic query as you have a single table and a single csv file so use it directly...